# Place image and textfield in the same class

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, textfield

My java code below is trying to place a image and a textfield in the same class. I am new to java programming I know in another languages I would just descale var pic = image and var text = textfield. That is all I am looking for in this java code. Just declare a textfield and image and have it display in the same window.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.*;  

class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args0) {

        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            File imageFile = new File("/Users/johnzalubski/Desktop/j/gg.jpg");
            Image i = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(i);
            JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
            frame.add(imageLabel);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            imageLabel.setLocation(0, 0);
            imageLabel.setSize(300, 250);
            imageLabel.setVisible(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(1000, 750);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JFrame f= new JFrame("TextField Example");  

            JTextField t1,t2;  
            t1=new JTextField("Welcome to Javatpoint.");  
            t1.setBounds(50,100, 200,30);  
            t2=new JTextField("AWT Tutorial");  
            t2.setBounds(50,150, 200,30);  
            frame.add(t1); f.add(t2);  
            frame.setSize(4000,400);  
            frame.setLayout(null);  
            frame.setVisible(true);  

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);` would be your first mistake. You should start by reading through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: 1) `File imageFile = new File("/Users/johnzalubski/Desktop/j/gg.jpg");` Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 2) `frame.setSize(4000,400);` What the..? You really have a screen res. that spans 4000 pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example to get you going. Note the comments to follow:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args0) {

        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            //use public resources when posting questions or answers
            URL url = new URL("http://www.digitalphotoartistry.com/rose1.jpg");
            ImageIcon image= new ImageIcon(url);
            JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
            //add the label to the frame using the default layout manager (BorderLayout)
            frame.add(imageLabel); //add label to the default position BorderLayout.CENTER
            //frame.setLayout(null); //do not use null layout
            //imageLabel.setLocation(0, 0); //do not set bounds, that is the job of the layout manager

            JTextField t1 =new JTextField("Welcome to Javatpoint.");
            frame.add(t1, BorderLayout.SOUTH); //add text field to the frame using BorderLayout other position
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: there is no need for `Main` to extend `JFrame`. It was just a leftover.